# Google Earth Engine pixels's spatial resolution of Suomi NPP VIIRS DNB nighttime lights data

Tags: google-earth-engine, night-time-images

I would like to know in meters exactly the pixels' spatial resolution corresponding to :15 Arc Seconds" of *VIIRS Nighttime Day/Night Band Composites Version 1* data from Google Earth Engine downloadable at:

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/NOAA_VIIRS_DNB_MONTHLY_V1_VCMCFG

in general I have found in several places the pixel spatial resolution to be about 750 m, however other sources indicate ~ 500 m for VIIIRS DNB, I would like to know exactly for the data provided by Google Earth Engine *VIIRS Nighttime Day/Night Band Composites Version 1* which is there defined as "15 Arc Second" to how many meters corresponds?

Comment: Over an ellipsoid, _15 arc seconds of latitude_ and _15 arc seconds of longitude_ are different functions of: - the parameters of the ellipsoid; and - the latitude. We can assume that we know the parameters of the ellipsoid that you are referring, but we don't know the latitude at which you want to know how many _meters_ are _15 arc seconds_.

Comment: I'm referring to a region at coordinates: List (2 elements)
0: [35.04774222355445,32.18393074977223]
0: 35.04774222355445
1: 32.18393074977223
1: [35.0504888055857,32.23505646762367]
0: 35.0504888055857
1: 32.23505646762367does the point location coordinates help to this purpose ?

Comment: is there a formula to calculate the conversion of ArcSeconds to meters based on lat Lon?

Comment: Charles Karney wrote the powerfull [GeographicLib](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/) program, so no need to reinvent the wheel. But if you want to know more about wheels, yes, there are formulas to calculate the length of meridian and paralells arcs and you can ask a question about them. Note that meridian and parallel arcs are rhumb lines, so you can use the [Online Rumb line Solver](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/cgi-bin/RhumbSolve) to get their lengths.

Comment: For instance, 15 seconds of a meridian arc from latitude 33 degrees to the North returns 462.102m: https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/cgi-bin/RhumbSolve?type=I&input=33d00%2700%22N+0d00%2700%22E+33d00%2715%22N+0d00%2700%22E&format=d&prec=3&radius=6378137&flattening=1%2F298.257223563&option=Submit , and a 15 seconds arc of the 33 degrees parallel returns 389.388m: https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/cgi-bin/RhumbSolve?type=I&input=33d00%2700%22N+0d00%2700%22E+33d00%2700%22N+0d00%2715%22E&format=d&prec=3&radius=6378137&flattening=1%2F298.257223563&option=Submit .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it's 463.83121534928955 meters.

```
var image = ee.ImageCollection("NOAA/VIIRS/DNB/MONTHLY_V1/VCMCFG").first()
print(
  image.projection().nominalScale()
)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/41af0300627c86978d60ae60528652f1